# timeout function for node?

Tags: node.js, stream

As far as my understanding goes this is a `stream` so it is constantly streaming values to the Oracle database.

I'm wondering if I can do a timeout function to wait about 3 seconds before sending again.

```
var net = require('net');
var fs = require('fs');
var oracledb = require('oracledb');
var dbConfig = require('./dbconfig.js');


var client = new net.Socket();

client.connect(8080, "192.168.0.7");

console.log("Client most likely connected...");


oracledb.getConnection(
    {
      user          : dbConfig.user,
      password      : dbConfig.password,
      connectString : dbConfig.connectString
    },
    function(err, connection) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        return;
      }
      client.on('data', function (data) {
        var weight_data = Number(data);
        console.log('Data: ' + data);
        connection.execute("INSERT INTO UNI_SCRAP_SCALE(WEIGHT) VALUES (:weight)", [weight_data], function (err, result) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log("Rows inserted: " + result.rowsAffected);
          console.log('Data received from Db:\n');
          console.log(result);
          connection.commit(
            function (err) {
              console.log('Done')
            });
          });
        });
      });
    });



// client.destroy();
```

Comment: So I put setTimeout in 3 separate locations. If the connection.execute was inside the setTimeout block, it would error saying it needed a callback. So I tried putting it below for the 3 console.logs and it waited on that code for 3 seconds then began executing as if the setTimeout was no longer there(i suppose setTimeout is only a one time thing). Obviously Node was a poor choice. Maybe using sockets was a bad choice as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is a function to set timeout in JavaScript, setTimeout(), here is an example :

```
setTimeout(function {
    // place your code here
}, 3000);   //number of millisecond before executing code
```

Your code will be executed after 3 seconds.

Documentation : 
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: Your statement about a timeout disappearing inside a function is just plain wrong.

Comment: Oh i tested again and you're right. I'm sure i faced a case where setInterval() and setTimeout() nested in some function or something else disappear. I will investigate.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    // code you want to wait for here
}, 3000);
```